# Numerus beim Zahlenwort Null

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

Ist es zu erklären (und, falls ja, wie?), dass man das Zahlenwort *null* als Mehrzahl behandelt, obschon es sogar weniger als Einzahl ist?

> Zwei Äpfel werden gegessen.
>   Ein Apfel wird gegessen.
>   Null Äpfel werden gegessen.

Welche andere Mengenauffassung von nicht gegessen werdenden Äpfeln hat man, wenn man etwa *null* durch *kein* ersetzt und dabei wiederum Singular verwendet?

> Kein Apfel wird gegessen.

**Nachträgliche Erläuterung:**
Hier soll es vollkommen unerheblich sein, dass man anstelle von *null* üblicherweise eher *kein/e* verwenden würde. Die Frage ist hauptsächlich, wieso

> Null Apfel wird gegessen.

so falsch klingt (jedenfalls in meinen Ohren). Die zweite Frage, die nach Unterschieden bei der Verwendung von *kein* und *null* fragt, ist eher als Denkanstoß gedacht, der vielleicht hilfreich zur Beantwortung sein könnte. Vielleicht auch nicht.

Comment: Und was ist mit *keine Äpfel?*

Comment: _Null_ ist ein ziemlich junges Wort, das Konzept ist erst in der Neuzeit ins Deutsche eingeführt worden.

Comment: Ich glaube, es liegt schlicht daran, dass null ungleich eins ist und nur eins im Singular steht.

Comment: @chirlu: Das könnte tatsächlich ein guter Erklärungsansatz sein.

Comment: Auch bei Dezimalbrüchen verwendet man den Plural, selbst bei 1,0.

Comment: @Carsten S: Schöne Beobachtung! Meine Theorie dazu: Das Komma ist wie ein "und" lesbar (was auch sinnvoll ist, weil es ja ein Plus darstellt). Also sind 1,0 Äpfel "ein und null zehntel Äpfel".

Answer (score 5):

Die Verwendung von *Null* ist in diesem Zusammenhang nimmt zwar mehr und mehr zu, ist aber eigentlich unüblich. Eher würde man sagen

> Kein Apfel wird gegessen
>   Keine Äpfel werden gegessen

*Null* in diesem Sinne ersetzt jedoch zunehmend die Wörter *kein* oder *keine*. So zum Beispiel in

> Ich habe null Bock
>   Null Ahnung, wie das gehen soll

Und siehe: Singular in beiden Formulierungen.

Hinzu kommt, dass in vielen Situationen von einem Plural ausgegangen wird, wenn die eigentliche Menge nicht bekannt ist.

> Wieviele Freunde hast Du?
>   Welche Bücher hast Du schon gelesen?

Auch hier wird ein Plural impliziert.

> Sorry, sie haben 0 Punkte (von möglichen X Punkten)

Hier wird die Formulierung *Sie haben keine Punkte* vermischt mit der nummerischen Angabe, so dass es hier zum Plural kommt, wobei die Formulierung *Sie haben keinen Punkt* auch möglich wäre. Dabei fehlt jedoch die Konnotation, dass nicht nur ein Punkt, sondern mehrere möglich gewesen wären.

Comment: Mathematisch muss ich dem ersten Satz widersprechen, denn Null ist die Mächtigkeit (=„Anzahl“ der Elemente) der leeren Menge.

Comment: Gut, dann müsste ich als Informatiker sprechen, da ist *null* wirklich *nicht definiert*. Aber dann formuliere ich es nochmal ohne Mathematik. Ist eh besser, weil es ja ein Sprachforum ist :-)

Comment: Null Bock und null Ahnung - "Zwei Böcke" und "Zwei Ahnungen" gibt es nicht.

Comment: *Um die Tür aufzulegen brauchen wir zwei Böcke* und *Ich habe da so eine Ahnung und du auch, aber unsere beiden Ahnungen widersprechen sich.*

Comment: Interessanter Hinweis auf "null Bock" und "null Ahnung" (ist wohl aber sehr umgangssprachlich), übrigens habe ich - wenngleich sehr vereinzelt - auch schon "Ich hab null Böcke" gehört. Meine Frage sehe ich hier allerdings nicht eigentlich beantwortet.

Answer (score 3):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl wird der Singular (*die Einzahl*) nur für *eins* verwendet.

Für alle anderen Fälle kommt der Plural zum Tragen. Dies gilt auch für Dezimalzahlen kleiner als eins.

Korrekt ist also

> Null Äpfel werden gegessen

Comment: *0,5 Äpfel* aber *ein halber Apfel*. Schon wieder etwas interessantes.

Comment: @Jan Und dann gibt es noch eine Halbzeit, obwohl Zeit unzählbar ist. :-)

Comment: Aaaaber die, genau wie die Drittelzeit, ist eindeutig ein Kompositum ;)

Comment: @Jan: Gut, dass es ein halber Apfel ist, ist ja klar. Weil man da nicht ganze, sondern halbe Äpfel als Einheiten zählt. Genau so bei ein Drittel, ein Viertel etc.